# GRAPH API for friends not returning more than 20 result

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to get list of all friends.
API is returning only 20 result.

However, when I tried with offset value = 21, it didn't returned any result.
Also, tried having limit = 500, still it returned only 20 results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use paging to get more than 20: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#paging

Check if there is a paging object in the result of your API call.